# Is it possible to have a compound foreign key in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, has-many

Suppose the following data schema:

```
Usage
======
client_id
resource
type
amount

Billing
======
client_id
usage_resource
usage_type
rate
```

In this example, suppose I have multiple resources, each of which can be used in many ways.  For example, one resource is a `widget`.  `Widgets` can be `foo`ed and they can be `bar`ed.  `Gizmo`s can also be `foo`ed and `bar`ed.  These usage types are billed at different rates, possibly even different rates for different clients.  Each occurence of a usage (of a resource) is recorded in the Usage table.  Each billing rate (for client, resource, and type combination) is stored in the billing table.

*(By the way, if this data schema is not the right way to approach this problem, please make suggestions.)*

Is it possible, using Ruby on Rails and ActiveRecord, to create a `has_many` relationship from Billings to Usages so that I can get a list of usage instances for a given billing rate?  Is there a syntax of the `has_many, :through` that I don't know?

Once again, I may be approaching this problem from the wrong angle, so if you can think of a better way, please speak up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is apparently an project at sourceforge to extend Rails' ActiveRecord with support for [Composite Primary Keys](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/).  I haven't used this extension, but it might help you.  It's also a gem at rubyforge.

Plain Ruby on Rails, as of version 2.0, does not support compound primary keys (cf. [HowToUseLegacySchemas](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/howtouselegacyschemas)).  Every table must have a single-column, auto-increment key named "`id`".

The explanation I have seen is: "You only need compound primary keys if you want to use a legacy database." This is of course a ridiculously ignorant view of data modeling.

The solution I see would be:

- Usage.client_id -> Client.id
- Usage.type_id -> Usagetype.id
- Usage.resource_id -> Resource.id
- Billing.usage_id -> Usage.id
- Billing.client_id -> Client.id
- Billing.type_id -> Usagetype.id
- Billing.resource_id -> Resource.id

The apparently redundant foreign keys in `Billing` attempt to enforce partial referential integrity.  But it doesn't quite get there -- it does not prevent you from creating rows in `Billing` that reference a row in `Usage` with the wrong client/resource/usagetype combination, not matching those in the referencing row in the Billing table.

**edit:** @Yarik: yes, you're right.  It makes more sense for `Usage` to reference `Billing`.

- Usage.billing_id -> Billing.id

Hmm.  I made an ER diagram but I'm having trouble inserting it as an image.

Comment: Wait a second... Shouldn't it be the other way around - a primary key in Billing and a foreign key in Usage??

Comment: Good answer, good background. The RoR view of databases seems to me problematic. But the dbms seems to have exacted its revenge by burdening RoR with a reputation as a slow, unscalable database hog.

Answer (score 1):

You can create any constraint you want with the 'execute' command in a migration.

You would probably want to add some error handling to .save to deal with cases when the constraint throws an error.

You can't use AR's built-in method generators to generate the usages off the billing, but you can still have the method:

```
class Billing
  def usages
    Usage.find(:all, :conditions => ["x = ? and y = ?", self.x, self.y])
  end
end
```