# has_many with two foreign_keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i know there are many questions regarding this subject, but i think my case is a little bit different.

*using rails 2.3.8*

I have two models, User and Message.

Table messages has columns sender_id and recipient_id and both references users table. I could  do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :messages_as_sender, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  has_many :messages_as_recipient, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'

  def messages
     messages_as_sender + messages_as_recipient
  end
end
```

In most cases it might be enough, but what if i want to do this:

```
user.messages.all(:limit => 10)
or
user.messages.all(:conditions => "some condition")
```

Rails provide something for this?

UPDATE

i was hoping something more clear but i end up with somethin like gayavat said thanks

Comment: Self-referential relationships are ugly, ugly beasts in Rails. To find additional information you'll want to search for the terms "self-referential relationships" and "compound foreign keys". Here are some resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279791/is-it-possible-to-have-a-compound-foreign-key-in-rails and http://asciicasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Comment: I don't know if Rails 2 does, but in Rails 3 that would already be working for you.

Comment: You should also consider giving named_scopes a try. Here's some more info: http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/8/20/named-scope-it-s-not-just-for-conditions-ya-know

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
def self.messages
  Messages.all(:conditions => ["sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?", self.id, self.id])
end
```